# Adding a menu item to Joomla's tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, joomla, tinymce, joomla-extensions, tinymce-plugins

So I created a WordPress plugin, but my client also wants it for Joomla... I need to add an item to the 'Insert' menu list in Joomla's tinymce editor. How would this be possible? Can I make an installable plugin for this without having to manually edit files? The documentation for this is lacking, and the standalone tinymce documentation isn't very helpful for Joomla's implementation.

I've created a directory and plugin.js within /media/vendor/tinymce/plugins/ for the plugin I want to create, as well as added the menu code, but I can't get it to populate in the editor's menu list. Perhaps I'm not understanding how the plugins are loaded? It doesn't seem to be as straight forward as making a regular Joomla plugin. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.